# UDP Packet reordering

Tags: java, networking, udp, sip, voip

I am making  VOIP  calling  Android app . where I have partially completed it using simple UDP without using SIP , RTP etc... 
When I am trying it in my Home LAN , quality is very good.
But when  I am using it over internet , sound quality is very poor for jitter .

Now the thing is in receiver side  I need to  RE-ORDER  received packet. I don’t want to use RTP  as it involved extra coding at this moment.

In receive loop I am receiving UDP  packet constantly and sending it to speaker.
I need to buffer those received packet and send it in order to speaker.

```
    While(true){
    byte[] data = new byte[..];
    Udpsocket.receive(data);
    // Store data in a big buffer. after receiving enough packets say 500 packets 
    // properly send to Speaker in proper order
    }
```

I was looking  Linux TCP code for packet reordering but it is very complex for me.

Can you please tell me how to reorder efficiently? I mean how much data I need to buffer etc. etc. how long I need to wait for data ..
any suggestion ,  sample code  or simple algorithm  for reordering UDP packet  will be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: "_in receiver side I need to RE-ORDER received packet._" You really don't want to do that for VoIP. VoIP will discard old data received out of order. By buffering, you are introducing a delay, and it becomes noticeable to the parties to the communication. Real-time protocols, like VoIP, simply ignore old data received out of order. Buffering can work if you are only receiving recorded sound from one direction, but in a two-way conversation, buffering doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. But I am telling that if  I receive two packets with sequence number 3 and  4  without any delay. But  if seq 3 comes just after seq 4 ..Still I do not need to reorder..Here I no need to wait at all ...

Comment: or you mean I will just drop packet with seq no  3  which comes after seq 4.... Overall it will increase number  of dropped packets and call quality will be poor.. is not it..

Comment: Call quality can be made worse, or it can end up with a noticeable delay. Real-time protocols like VoIP or video assume some packets will be lost or received out-of-order, and they are OK with that and deal with it. They do not introduce delay by buffering, resending lost packets, or reordering packets. Whe a packet arrives out of order, it is most likely that the previous packet was lost, and waiting for a lost packet is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Make each packet you send contain a header. Each header have a sequence number. Increase the sequence number sequentially for each packet sent.

If the receiver gets a packet whose sequence number if out of order, keep it for a short while to see if the correct one arrives later. If not then use the packet anyway as the next packet.

Comment: Yes. That part is implemented - sequence number. I mean how much data I need to buffer etc. etc. how long I need to wait for data .. any suggestion , sample code or simple algorithm for reordering UDP packet will be appreciated .

Comment: I am also looking for a simple implementation of a buffer to sort packages. Especially correctly handling overflows of the sequence number seems to be not trivial.